# Python tkmacosx error: "systemWindowBackgroundColor"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I am trying to change the foreground color of a button. I am using a mac big sur and I installed tkmacosx but I believe there is an issue with tkmacosx.

Running the following code, or trying to use button2 in general, raises an error:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkmacosx import Button


window = tk.Tk()


button = tk.Button(window, text='Text', highlightbackground='gray15', fg='pink')
button.pack()

button2 = Button(window, text='Text')#, highlightbackground='gray15', fg='pink')
button2.pac()

window.mainloop()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/BPF_Program/Save Logs/May 9, 2021/Tkinter stackoverflow thing.py", line 11, in <module>
    button2 = Button(window, text='Text')#, highlightbackground='gray15', fg='pink')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/widgets/button.py", line 55, in __init__
    ButtonBase.__init__(self, 'normal', master, cnf, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidgets/button_base.py", line 1045, in __init__
    _Canvas.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/utils/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, 'canvas', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2569, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "systemWindowBackgroundColor"
```

Comment: *"systemWindowBackgroundColor"* normaly starts with a capital *S*.

Comment: @Atlas435 I went in and changed the s as you suggested, SYSTEM_DEFAULT_BG = "SystemWindowBackgroundColor" and the error was the same

Comment: Use [tkmacosx v1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/1.0.0/) instead, you can do `pip install tkmacosx==1.0.0`

Comment: Btw are you using macOS? if yes, then what os version are you on? Let me know so I can fix the bug or you can report the bug [here](https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkmacosx/issues/new?assignees=Saadmairaj&labels=bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) with all the details.

Comment: @Saad I'm on Big Sur 11.2.3

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a problem as `"systemWindowBackgroundColor"` and `"systemTextColor"` are macOS specific colours that are supported after high sierra. What python version and Tkinter are you using and how did you install python?

Answer (score 0):

I had to hard code in values systemWindowBackgroundColor and systemTextColor for them to not raise an error. The change is the 2nd variable for each SYSTEM_DEFAULT_BG and SYSTEM_DEFAULT_FG. This was in my `tkmacosx/utils/__init__.py` file.

```
SYSTEM_DEFAULT_BG = "white"
SYSTEM_DEFAULT_FG = "black"
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    SYSTEM_DEFAULT_BG = "systemWindowBackgroundColor"
    SYSTEM_DEFAULT_BG = "#FFFFFF"
    SYSTEM_DEFAULT_FG = "systemTextColor"
    SYSTEM_DEFAULT_FG = "#000000"
```

It may not be the proper fix but it seems to do the job.

Comment: Modify source code of module directly is not recommended because the changes will be lost after the module is upgraded.